# Play On LInux missing buttons in plasma

Tags: python, playonlinux, scaling, plasma-5, hdpi

Please help me fix play on linux on the Plasma Desktop.
My version of kde is below
Ubuntu Xenial
[image]

My Play on linux trouble is here.

[image]

I'm scaling the desktop to 1.5 on a microsoft surface pro 3

The icons are all terrible and there are no buttons so I can't click on anything.

TIA

Comment: scaling seems to be the problem.  I am now using the ubuntu-mate method of scaling, which seems to fix the problem for me personally but does not address the issue that python apps have with plasma dpi scaling.

Comment: "#!/bin/sh
 xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1x1
 xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 0.6x0.6" 
Is the script I now use for dpi scaling in plasma